# configuring stripe webhook, Test webhook error: Unable to connect

Tags: php, stripe-payments, webhooks

So I am trying to implement a stripe webhook to listen to various events. Basically I have my php application running live, say on "http://example.com". I have installed the stripe CLI and have  all the classes. I already have created a webhook on stripe dashboard. But when I test a webhook it gives me this error :

> "Test webhook error: Unable to connect. Timed out connecting to remote
> host"

I am coding on PhpStorm from  where I save the files and they get reflected on my website "abc.com". Here is my php file code

```
    require_once 'abc.com/httpdocs/includes/classes/stripe-sdk/vendor/stripe/stripe-php/configuration.php';
require_once 'abc.com/httpdocs/includes/classes/stripe-sdk/vendor/stripe/stripe-php/init.php';

$endpoint_secret = 'whsec_...';
$payload = file_get_contents('php://input');
$event = null;

$sig_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'];
try {
    $event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent(
        $payload, $sig_header, $endpoint_secret
    );
} catch(\Stripe\Exception\SignatureVerificationException $e) {
    // Invalid signature
    echo '⚠️  Webhook error while validating signature.';
    http_response_code(400);
    exit();
}

// Handle the event
switch ($event->type) {
    case 'account.updated':
        $paymentIntent = $event->data->object; 
        break;
    default:
        // Unexpected event type
        error_log('Received unknown event type');
}

http_response_code(200);
```

I don't think I have to run the php server on a local host. And do I need to "stripe listen .."?
Hoping to get an answer! Thanks in advance :) Let me  know  if you need any other information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was the problem with my EC2 server permission. I had to add the stripe "ip's" to the Allowed Hosts! That was it :)

Comment: hi Zain, how do you get stripe "ip's" and how do you set them in EC2?

Comment: @titan - you can find list of ip's here https://stripe.com/docs/ips - Secondly click the EC2 instance, go to the "Security" tab then click on the associated "Security groups". Then click the "Edit Inbound Rules" and paste that list of IP's there. You can easily find additional things on the internet :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like whatever is trying to connect to your webhook endpoint URL can’t reach said endpoint. Can you clarify the following…

If you are testing local code:
Make sure your local PHP server is up and running and make a note of the port it is running on. Then, run `stripe listen --forward-to http://localhost:<PHP server’s port>`. From there you can trigger sample events from a new CLI window like so: `stripe trigger invoice.payment_succeeded`. Take a look at the docs for this [here.](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/test#listen-for-events)

If you are setting up a live endpoint:
I'd first recommend using something like Postman to verify that you can indeed reach the server where your webhook code is deployed. Then, I’d double check the entry you have for that webhook endpoint URL in the dashboard.

If you can pinpoint where you’re stuck, I can provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: Hi @codename_duches! Thanks for your time. Actually I have my domain running on EC2 server. I created  a file there with the code mentioned above. When I go to my stripe dashboard to send a test event, it says "Unable to connect". I also tested it with the "listen" etc commands and it gave /404/ error. If you say I can provide the URL. Or if you agree we can have a video call meeting so I can share my screen! My email is "bsef17a020@pucit.edu.pk" Awaiting your response.

Comment: @MUHAMMADZAIN Are you able to reach any endpoints on the server with Postman? This sounds like a deployment issue.

Comment: Hi! So it was the problem with my EC2 server permission. I had to add the stripe "ip's" to the Allowed Hosts! Thanks by the way.